# What are the criteria to select the appropriate resolution to build a 2D game?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'd like to know, how can I select the best resolution to build a 2D game in android?

Comment: For Android, you don't get to select a resolution. The device's screen determines the resolution. You can use one of the Viewport classes (typically ExtendViewport) to define a world scale that is stretched to fit whatever resolution the screen is. Then you don't even have to think about resolution. (Unless you're making retro pixel-art, which takes more thought to really do properly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with 1920*1080 - this will give you a clear output on most current devices - and use `FitViewPort` or `ExtendViewPort` as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rendering my graphics in 2K resolution (i.e. in 3040 x 1,40 - aiming most popular high-end phones of today, i.e. Samsung S10) so it will definitely look well on screens with higher resolution. And then I'm using camera zoom to display it properly on current screen resolution. It does take a bit more space for graphics and it's probably loosing some frame per second but on today's devices it's acceptable loss. My games run smooth even on older devices, so I don't think it's an issue at all.